# PHP cURL - getting 302

Tags: php, curl, bots

I am trying to get content of website via cURL in PHP.

But everything, what i get back is just 302 pointing to homepage, so i think, this is some kind of bot protection.

Is there any chance to solve it?

Code :

```
$curl_handle = curl_init ("****");
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com/");
$output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
```

Comment: try setting `CURLOPT_REFERER` as its home page?

Comment: Did not work, i already tried this.